# Выборка из массива по заданому значению ключей

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [product_id] => 27861642
    [percent] => 100
    [price] => 1437.132
    [relateds] => 044650C020
)
[1] => Array (
    [product_id] => 27818936
    [percent] => 100
    [price] => 1521.984
    [relateds] => 0446560280
)
);
```

За один обход массива нужно сделать выборку (вывести 1 массив), в котором значение элемента [relateds] = 0446560280, а так же элемент [price] имеет наименьшее значение.

Comment: MasterAlex, а вы читали саму суть вопроса? У меня вопрос о том, как вывести массив с заданным значением элемента, а не только наименьшее значение

Comment: а в чём проблема то, берёте все массивы у которых [relateds] = 0446560280 для этого не нужна сортировка, а дальше  сортируете их по [price], как сделано по ссылке, потом выводите первое значение. У вас в вопросе явно написано, что проблемы с сортировкой, а не проблема с выводом всех элементов у которых значение равно чему-то

Comment: @cert, сортировка и фильтрация -- две разных задачи (не стоит мешать их в одну кучу). Вопрос о _сортировке_ - дубликат. Вопрос о сложной выборке -- _возможно_ нет. Что-то мне подсказывает, что вы хотите решать задачу в один обход массива, но из вопроса этого не видно. Если это действительно так -- внесите необходимые правки в вопрос

Comment: Dmitriy Simushev, спасибо за пояснение, сейчас внесу правки.

Comment: если Вы хотите поделиться решением проблемы с которой Вы столкнулись, то оформите вопрос/ответ *правильно*: отредактируйте исходный вопрос, а решение перенесите в ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение:

```
function is_min_price_analogs(array $a, $b){
    $min_price = 9999999;
    $min_item = -1;
        if(count($a)){
            foreach($a as $i => $item){
                if(isset($item['price'])  AND ($item['price'] < $min_price) AND ($item['articles'] !== $b)){
                    $min_price = $item['price'];
                    $min_item_key = $i; // ключ массива
                    $min_item = $item; // array
                }
            }
        }
    return $min_item;
}
```

Использовать можно так:

```
$your_variable = is_min_price($products[2], $pattern);
$название_переменной = is_min_price(входящий массив, значение_которое_ищем_в_элементе);
```